# Azure Functions - get parameter value in middleware

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I am running a `v4` Azure Function in an isolated process. It is triggered by a message coming from a Service Bus queue. I have created a simple middleware and would like to get my hands on the incoming data (a simple string). How can I do that from the middleware itself? It doesn't seem `FunctionContext` is of use in this case.

```
public class SimpleMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        await next(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The service bus message data and metadata is extracted and placed into the `BindingData` dictionary. Try looking at `context.BindingContext.BindingData` and find the key that exposes your message's data.